# How create a 'product-filter' in a shop using Django?

Tags: python, django, filtering, pyodbc

I am creating a chocolate shop in Django together with SQL.

Currently, I can connect to the SQL database and show all the existing chocolates in my chocolate-menu.html file. I would like to integrate a filter menu, so that people can filter chocolates by price, flavour, etc.

I show all the chocolates using the following function in views.py:

```
def showChocoMenu(request):
    connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xxx;Uid=xxxx@xx;Pwd=xxx;Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;')
    cur = connection.cursor() 
    cur.execute("SELECT choco_name, choco_price FROM chocolates c, stock s WHERE c.choco_ID=s.choco_ID AND s.availability > 0 AND s.country ='UK'")
    chocolateMenu = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    connection.close() 
    return HttpResponse(render_to_string('chocolate_menu.html',{'chocolateMenu':chocolateMenu}))
```

This is the filter menu I've created in the chocolate-menu.html file.

```
<table width = "50%" class = "center_filter" style ="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td width = "10%" class = "no_border"> <span style = "color:9A8478;font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial;font-weight: bolder; font-size:20px">Filter by</span> </td>
                    <td width = "10%"> <span style = "color:C39A6B;  font-weight: bold; font-size:18px">Price </span></td>
                    <td width = "10%"> <span style = "color:C39A6B;  font-weight: bold; font-size:18px">Flavour </span></td>
                    <td width = "10%"> <span style = "color:C39A6B;  font-weight: bold; font-size:18px">Special Diet </span></td>
                    <td width = "10%"> <span style = "color:C39A6B; font-weight: bold; font-size:18px">Calories </span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class = "no_border"></td>
                    <td>  <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="five_to_ten" value='five_to_ten' >&pound;5 - &pound;10</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="dark" value = 'dark'>Dark </td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="lactose_free" value='lactose_free'>Lactose-free </td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="zero_to_hundret" value = 'zero_to_hundret'>  0 - 100 </td>
                </tr>
                    <td class = "no_border"></td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 10px" id="ten_to_twenty" value ='ten_to_twenty' >&pound;10 - &pound;20</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 10px" id="white" value = 'white'>White </td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 10px" id="sugar_free" value = 'sugar_free'>Sugar-free </td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 10px" id="hundret_to_twofifty" value='hundret_to_twofifty'>100 - 250 </td>
                </tr>    
                
            </table>
```

I guess I could use include a form with method POST to call a filter function, but I have no clue how to do so in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Django has [an ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) that you can use to avoid having to write plain SQL. This makes interacting with your models much easier. So for a model like:

```
class Chocolate(model.Model):
     availability = models.IntegerField(...)
     country = models.CharField(...)
     ...
```

you can make queries that return `QuerySet` objects (groupings of django model instances returned from the query):

```
chocolates = Chocolate.objects.all() # This will get all chocolates
chocolates = Chocolate.objects.filter(availability__gt = 0)
chocolates = Chocolate.objects.filter(country='UK')
chocolates = Chocolate.objects.filter(availability__gt = 0, country='UK')
```

You should read through the document mentioned above to get familiar with making queries in general, then see the [different queries you can achieve with the orm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/), and also read through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: You are right, but I guess she is using a database not supported oficially by django. Anyway she can use [django-pyodbc](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/). You may as well want to include some link to [django forms doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/).